# How Kotlin's coroutine is cancelled under the hood?

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, kotlin-coroutines

Suppose we have a `CoroutineScope` and we launched several coroutines from it via `launch`. Then we do `CoroutineScope.cancel()`. And then we need to wait until cancellation finishes and all children of this scope will be canceled via `job.join()`. My questions are:

1. On what factors does cancellation time depend? Can I reduce the time somehow?

I know that if the coroutine is calculating something, and does not check
for cancellation, then it won't be canceled. But what if the
coroutine is suspended? The coroutine will be canceled only when it "resumes"?

2. When in my coroutine I collect values from the flow via `flow.collect`, and then I cancel coroutine, the coroutine will be canceled only when a new value will be emitted into the flow, yes? Or when the flow will be canceled?

Comment: It cancels immediately if suspended, which includes when it's waiting for the next item from a Flow. It also *only* gets cancelled when it reaches a suspension.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please elaborate on this please: Is it written somewhere in documentation? Or do you know this from source code?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I think this is not entirely true. Suspension could be cancellable or not. In practice all or almost all utility functions from stdlib are cancellable and often this is explicitly mentioned in the function description. However, for example `suspendCoroutine()` is not cancellable. If cancelled it still waits at the suspension point and it even resumes normally, because it doesn't automatically check the cancelled flag.

Comment: @broot, Good point. I kind of take it for granted that suspend functions always cooperate with cancellation, but that can be subverted if you write one that doesn't or you use `suspendCoroutine`. I'm not sure, but isn't that the *only* suspend function in the kotlinx library that doesn't cooperate?